# How can I call an input value from a form in PHP?

Tags: php

So I have this code:

```
<input type="radio" name="theme" value="mPurpose" checked >mPurpose
<br>
<input type="radio" name="theme"  value="Portal" >Portal
```

and in the form process file I need to call the value of the radio.
I have this at the top of the form process:

```
$chkbox = $_POST['theme'];
```

So I could do something like

```
if( isset($chkbox['mPurpose']) )
```

but it can only call the name...how do I call the value? Thanks!

Comment: In your inputs you use the same name for both inputs.  The `name` attributes should be unique and the value for a checkbox, if the checkbox is checked, will be the value set in the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

(The value is already in the variable so do this)

```
if($chkbox  == "mPurpose")
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out some noobs!